# start ubuntu as terminal in project folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added the following line to my settings in VSCode:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\bd\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\ubuntu.exe"
```

When I now start a terminal ubuntu is started in my user's home folder. How is it possible to start ubuntu in the project folder?

The thing is wsl can start any linux that I set using `wsl /setdefault` I dont like to rely on such a setting but want to specify the one I want to start. I want it started in the project's folder.

Edit:
I change into some project directory and call `wslconfig.exe /s Legacy`. When I now invoke `wsl` `Bash` is started in the current folder.
I return to `cmd` and call `wslconfig.exe /s Ubuntu`. When I now call `wsl` `Store Ubuntu` is started in the current folder. 
`wsl.exe` seems to start Ubuntu differently than `ubuntu.exe` does. `ubuntu.exe` always starts in the user's home dir.

Comment: There were downvotes? Why?

Comment: There's an existing issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you want to run in the VSCode terminal is the Windows Subsystem for Linux (in particular the Ubuntu variant).

To do so, you should run `wsl.exe`, using this setting:

```js
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
```

This will start up a Windows Subsystem for Linux shell inside the terminal. If you have installed Ubuntu, that is what will be run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I set the shell to `wsl.exe' it starts in the project's folder.